# Can I loop through TextBox id's to check / change values in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project and I'm a beginner and I'm having a little trouble with this. I'm trying to check if a textbox is empty and if it is to change the value to N/A so that I can input n/a into a database instead of it not working.

Here is the code that I thought would work but didn't because the .Text property isn't near the ID anymore:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=17; i++)
{
if(!("tb" + i).Text)
"tb" + i.Text = "n/a";
}
```

I wasn't sure if the true/false would work but I never got to find out because it doesn't compile to begin with. I have 17 textboxes on my design page all with ID 'tb + i' e.g tb1, tb2

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop through the textbox ids, you have to find the control on the page first using the [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Then you can create your loop like this:

```
TextBox txt;
for(int i = 1; i<=17; i++)
{
    txt = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("tb" + i);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
        txt.Text = "n/a";
}
```

Comment: thanks, how can I use Textbox in my .cs file though?

Comment: What do you mean?  The TextBox class should be part of the ASP.NET library.  It's in the namespace `System.Web.UI.WebControls` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Textbox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It was because it's case sensitive I guess. I changed it to TextBox txt and it works now, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, typo on my part... updated my post for the correct case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
for(int i = 1; i<=17; i++)
{
    var textBox = Page.FindControl("tb" + i) as TextBox;

    if(textBox != null && textBox.Text == "") { ... }
}
```